# Vagrant not able to find home/vagrant/hiera.yaml

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I have inherited a python app that uses Puppet, Vagrant and VirtualBox to provision a local Centos test machine.

**This app was written on Mac and I'm developing on Windows.**

When I run `vagrant up` I see a large list of [command line errors](http://pastie.org/9112433), the most relevant of which is:

```
Running Puppet with site.pp..    
Warning: Config file /home/vagrant/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
WARN: Fri Apr 25 16:32:24 +0100 2014: Not using Hiera::Puppet_logger. It does not report itself to b
e suitable.
```

I know what Hiera is, and why it's important, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

The file hiera.yaml is present in the repo but it's not found at *home/vagrant/hiera.yaml*, instead it's found at *./puppet/manifests/hiera.yaml*.... Similarly if I ssh into the box, there is absolutely nothing whatsoever inside *home/vagrant* but I can find this file when I look in /tmp

So I'm confused, is vagrant looking inside the Virtual box and expecting this file to be found at *home/vagrant/hiera.yaml*? Or have I inherited an app that did not work properly in the first place? I'm really stuck here and I can't get in touch with the original dev.

Here are some details from my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Base box configuration ommitted    
  # Forwarded ports ommitted   
  # Statically set hostname and internal network to match puppet env ommitted

  # Enable provisioning with Puppet standalone 
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|

    # Tell Puppet where to find the hiera config
    puppet.options = "--hiera_config hiera.yaml --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests"

    # Boilerplate Vagrant/Puppet configuration
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"

    # Custom facts provided to Puppet
    puppet.facter = {
      # Tells Puppet that we're running in Vagrant
      "is_vagrant" => true,
    }
  end

  # Make the client accessible
  config.vm.synced_folder "marflar_client/", "/opt/marflar_client"
end
```

It's really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this `puppet.options` line that tells Puppet where to look for hiera.yaml and currently it simply specifies the file name. Now, when you run `vagrant up`, it mounts the current directory (the one that has the `Vagrantfile` in it) into `/vagrant` on the guest machine. Since you're saying `hiera.yaml` is actually found in `./puppet/manifests/hiera.yaml`, I believe you want to change the `puppet.options` line as follows:

```
puppet.options = "--hiera_config /vagrant/puppet/manifests/hiera.yaml --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests"
```

Comment: Probably worth noting hiera_config option is only available in Puppet 3.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer helped me get much farther than I was! Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this warning, you may first try to check from where this file is referenced, i.e.:

```
$ grep -Rn hiera.yaml /etc/puppet
/etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/spec/spec_helper_acceptance.rb:13:    on hosts, '/bin/touch /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml'
/etc/puppet/modules/mysql/spec/spec_helper_acceptance.rb:34:      shell("/bin/touch #{default['puppetpath']}/hiera.yaml")
```

In this case it's your vagrant file.

You may also try to find the right path to it via:

```
sudo updatedb && locate hiera.yaml
```

And either follow the @EvgenyChernyavskiy suggestion, create a symbolic link if you found the file:

```
sudo ln -vs /etc/hiera.yaml /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
```

or create the empty file (`touch /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml`).

In your case you should use the absolute path to your hiera.yaml file, instead of relative.

The warning should be gone.